# How to change this method to return an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, return-value

As can be seen below I've tried many times to return AddedNotes, but I don't know how to change the "VOID". I always get errors. Why?

```
public static void combine(ArrayList<String> arr, int k, int startId, String[] branch, int numElem) {

    if (numElem == k) {
        ArrayList<String> AddedNotes = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<branch.length;i++){  
            AddedNotes.add(branch[i]);  
        }  

        System.out.println(AddedNotes);
        return;

    }

    for (int i = startId; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
         branch[numElem++] = arr.get(i);
       combine(arr, k, ++startId, branch, numElem);
        --numElem;

    }

}
```

Most people tell me to do it like this, but it doesn't work, because I also need to return another ArrayList in the bottom of the method. But I only need to return AddedNodes.

```
public static ArrayList<String> combine(ArrayList<String> arr, int k, int startId, String[] branch, int numElem) {

    if (numElem == k) {
        ArrayList<String> AddedNotes = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<branch.length;i++){  
            AddedNotes.add(branch[i]);  
        }  

        System.out.println(AddedNotes);
        return AddedNotes;

    }

    for (int i = startId; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
         branch[numElem++] = arr.get(i);
       combine(arr, k, ++startId, branch, numElem);
        --numElem;

    }
```

Comment: * facepalm * Just change return type to ArrayList<String> and return AddedNotes;

Comment: no, i tried already but it occurs errors.

Comment: perhaps try to learn about Java syntax, instead of asking. Try some tutorials.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do a `--numElem` AFTER the recursion?

Comment: Your statement of `but i only need to return AddedNodes` doesn't make sense if you have any code following that block.

Comment: yes!! this method is to do a combination of a bunch of nodes.

Comment: Use better(longer) names for your parameter and variable names :)   k is not a nice parameter name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `combine` to return an ArrayList, just define it instead of `void`:

```
public static ArrayList<String> combine(ArrayList<String> arr, int k, int startId, String[] branch, int numElem) {
```

I am assuming `AddedNotes` is an `ArrayList<String>` and then return it:

```
    System.out.println(AddedNotes);
    return AddedNotes;
```

**NOTE: you will also need to return an Array (either AddedNotes, another Array, or null) at the end of the method, since a return is required. So either add another return there (outside of the loop) or return another array or null.**

You didn't provide enough details, so allow me to provide some advice, just in case:

1. You are not practicing defensive programming (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming). Specially for this code, returning AddedNotes will allow an external program to modify it. Unless you want it to be modified. Even in this case it would make more sense to allow the modifications to be done via methods, instead of directly via the ArrayList.
2. Your use of static is questionable, since the AddedNotes could be not initialized.

But overall, try to learn more about Java. There are excellent tutorials online, such as http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial

Comment: can you take at look above that I changed just like you said but it need me to return another ArrayList at the bottom of combine method.

Comment: You can't, @user3806299. A method can only return one thing. A method does its work, returns some data (or no data), and then it's done, fin, kaput. You can have several return statements in a method (`if this then return 1 else return 0`), but only one is actually going to be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that:

```
public static ArrayList<String> combine(...){ 
  ArrayList<String> AddedNotes = new ArrayList<String>(); 
  ... 

  return AddedNotes;
}
```

Yes, you need to return the `ArrayList` in the end of the method. The way you have it, if you don't enter the `if` condition, nothing will be returned, and that's why you're getting an error. The alternative is to return `null` otherwise.

Comment: no, its wrong to do like this, as i edited again above.